# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when reading and iterating over a file in Python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read and iterate over a text file in Python but I keep running into this error. I'm pretty new to Python and I'm not sure where the error in my code is:

```
import socket

def getBanner(ip, port):
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((ip, port))
        banner = s.recv(1024)
        return banner
    except:
        return

def vulnCheck(banner):
    f = open("vuln_banners.txt", 'r')
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.strip('\n') in banner:
            print("[+] Server is vulnerable: "+banner.strip('\n'))
        else:
            print("[-] FTP Server is not vulnerable.")
            return


def main():
    portList = [21, 22, 25, 80, 110, 443]
    for x in range(1, 255):
        ip = '192.168.1.' + str(x)
        for port in portList:
            banner = getBanner(ip, port)
            if banner:
                print("[+] " + str(ip) + ": " + str(banner))
                vulnCheck(banner)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would like my program to iterate over a list of strings in a text file to compare against a banner, however, every time I run the code I get this error:

```
  File "/home/testing/Documents/HelloWorld.py", line 17, in vulnCheck
    if line.strip('\n') in banner:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I've read few of the answers about this error and they talk about NOT opening the file as binary, but I don't think I'm doing that in my code. I'm simply trying to read each line in a text file and iterate over it. Can anyone point out the error in my code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Python 3 is  a bit of a pain as many communications and file buffers are now byte-objects rather than strings.  The simplest thing that usually works is `decode()` string method.  e.g. `mystring = mybuffer.decode()` .  You can also use `encode()` when going the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your socket returns `bytes` while the file contains strings. You need to map one to the other - probably decode `bytes` banners to strings.

As an aside, repeatedly reading the same static text file is a significant bottleneck here. Unless the file is so huge that you should be using a database instead anyway, read it once, at the start.

The following also has assorted bug fixes and stylistic updates; most importantly, don't `return` in the middle of the vulnerability check if the first vulerability wasn't matched. Notice also how functions generally just `return` a result, and leave it to the caller to decide e.g. whether to print something based on that.

```py
import socket

def get_banner(ip, port):
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((ip, port))
        banner = s.recv(1024)
        return banner.decode('utf-8')
    except:
        return

def vuln_check(banner, vulnlist):
    for line in vulnlist:
        if line in banner:
            return True
    return False

def read_vulns(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()

def main():
    vulns = read_vulns("vuln_banners.txt")

    port_list = [21, 22, 25, 80, 110, 443]
    for x in range(1, 255):
        ip = '192.168.1.' + str(x)
        for port in port_list:
            banner = get_banner(ip, port)
            if banner:
                print("[+]", ip + ":", banner)
                if vuln_check(banner, vulns):
                    print("[+] Server is vulnerable:", banner.strip('\n'))
                else:
                    print("[-] FTP Server is not vulnerable.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In `getBanner`, `banner = s.recv(1024)` is a `bytes` object, so `banner` in `vulnCheck` is also `bytes`. Since you did *not* open the file in binary mode, `line.strip('\n')` will be a *string*. It is an error to search for `str`ings in `bytes` because a string must be encoded in order to do this (or the bytes must be decoded appropriately).

Thus, you *should* indeed open the file in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

The banner object is not a string, so python can't search through a byte object, trying to find a string.